# Laratrust polymorphic user models returns wrong roles

Tags: laravel-6.2, laratrust

I am using [Laratrust](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/) to add roles to my `User` model. I want to add another table to use roles as well. I added `modelAs` to the config but Laratrust is confusing the two types. I get the roles from `user` with id[3] when querying `modelA` with id[3]. All I changed in the config was the user_models array like so:

```
'user_models' => [
    'users' => 'App\User',
    'modelAs' => 'App\ModelA'
],
```

I then added the modelA in `role_users` and set `user_type` to `App\ModelA`

```
|user_id    |role_id    |user_type        |
|-----------|-----------|-----------------|
|3          |6          |App\User         |
|3          |7          |App\User         |
|3          |8          |App\ModelA       |
```

Is the polymorphic relationship not supposed to know that I am not using the `User` model when I use the statement `$modelA->roles`?

I believe the problem has to do with caching the roles, because the key used to cache the roles in `redis` is `laratrust_roles_for_user_3` which would the same for both variations of `user_type`. So the Cached values are overwritten? How am I supposed to work around that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I took a deeper look at how the package stores values in the cache.
In the `LaratrustUserDefaultChecker` the cache key is built up using `$cacheKey = 'laratrust_roles_for_'.$this->userModelCacheKey() .'_'. $this->user->getKey();` and the `userModelCacheKey()` function is as follows:

```php
public function userModelCacheKey()
{
    if (!Config::get('laratrust.use_morph_map')) {
        return 'user';    // <-- this caused the confusion.
    }

    foreach (Config::get('laratrust.user_models') as $key => $model) {
        if ($this->user instanceof $model) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I am not using the `morph_map` setting, thus the key will be the same for models with the same ID. This is the cause of the confusion.
A quick test showed that if I set `'use_morph_map' => true` in the laratrust config and change the `user_type` column to match the `key` of `user_models` then there are two cache entries corresponding to my two models. And now `->hasRole` returns the correct result!

Note: I had to clear my cache before the test because it would show the wrong stored values.